# I can't fit an exponential function in a data set

Tags: python, curve-fitting, exponential

I have a data set from a laboratory that I did in which I studied the characteristics of current and voltage in a solar panel. The data is a bit inconsistent but it is visible that it is an exponential function. I need to determine the exponential function for my data set.

The exponential formula is this $I=I_s(\exp{\frac{e\cdot U}{k\cdot T}}-1)$. Where e, k, and T are constants.

My code that describes the formula and the data set:

```
data = [
    (64.5, -2.84),
    (85.4, -2.6),
    (111.7, -2.6),
    (137.1, -2.6),
    (162.3, -2.56),
    (188.1, -2.56),
    (214, -2.56),
    (238, -2.56),
    (262.2, -2.52),
    (283.5, -2.52),
    (367.3, -1.72),
    (388, -0.92),
    (393, -0.64),
    (395, -0.48),
    (399.3, -0.38),
    (400, -0.2)
]

# unpack the data into separate arrays
U_1, I_1 = zip(*data)
def exponential(x, a, b):
    print(a*(np.exp(b*x)-1))
    return a*(np.exp(b*x)-1)
```

I plot it like this:

```
# fit the curve to the data, using the weights
params, params_covariance = curve_fit(exponential, U_1, I_1,p0=initial_params)
# plot the data and the fit
plt.plot( U_1, I_1,'bo', label='data')

# compute the fitted curve point by point
U_1_fit = np.linspace(min(U_1), max(U_1), 1000)
I_1_fit = exponential(U_1_fit, *params)
plt.plot(U_1_fit, I_1_fit, 'r', label='fit')
```

The exponential function was in the millions so I gave an initial parameter:

```
initial_params = [0, -3]
```

It is stuck, for some reason, on the value -1.89125. I tried different methods and they didn't work or gave me the same answer of -1.89125. I just need to be an exponential that makes sense for my data.

Comment: Pro tip: consider log-transforming your supposedly exponential data prior to fit (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/454999). It won't get stuck and is often numerically more stable, but gives you a different result. Although you would often want it instead, anyway -  it "optimizes" the estimation of the exponent instead of the regular least squares in the original space. And you also get to see very clearly if it is exponential, hyperexponential, hypoexponential...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a third parameter `c` to make your model more flexible. Then, the initial value for `b` is wrong, it cannot be negative.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = [
    (64.5, -2.84),
    (85.4, -2.6),
    (111.7, -2.6),
    (137.1, -2.6),
    (162.3, -2.56),
    (188.1, -2.56),
    (214, -2.56),
    (238, -2.56),
    (262.2, -2.52),
    (283.5, -2.52),
    (367.3, -1.72),
    (388, -0.92),
    (393, -0.64),
    (395, -0.48),
    (399.3, -0.38),
    (400, -0.2)
]

data = np.array(data)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a * (np.exp(b * x) - 1) + c

p0 = [1, 0.02, 0]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=p0)

plt.scatter(x, y)
xx = np.linspace(50, 400, 1000)
plt.plot(xx, f(xx, *popt))
plt.show()
```

[image]